# Remove See More (Default view for everything) in Actionable Message Microsoft teams

Tags: json, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I've successfully created a script to post to a microsoft team via the incoming hooks connector however when it posts the message the potentialActions are always hidden behind a see more tag. Is there a way to force this to always be displayed?

Code for reference:

```
$data = array(
        '@type' => "MessageCard",
        '@context' => "http://schema.org/extensions",
        'themeColor' => "1B2C58",
        'summary' => "BOT has closed a sale!",
        'sections' => array(
        0 => array(
            'activityTitle' => $username . " has closed a sale!",
            'facts' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => "Customer",
                'value' => $accname), 
            1 => array(
                'name' => "Product",
                'value' => $interestTitle . " - " . $opTypeArray[$opType] . $extra), 
            2 => array(
                'name' => "Sales Value",
                'value' => $value . " (excl. VAT)"), 
            3 => array(
                'name' => "Purchase order",
                'value' => $poInput),
                ),
            'markdown' => True
            ),
        ),
        'potentialAction' => array(
            0 => array(
                '@type' => "ActionCard",
                'name' => "Add a comment",
                'inputs' => array(
                0 => array(
                    '@type' => "TextInput",
                    'id' => "comment",
                    'title' => "Enter your comment",
                    'isMultiline' => true),
                    ),
                    ),
            1 => array(
                '@type' => "OpenUri",
                'name' => "View Opportunity on ADM",
                'targets' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'os' => "default",
                    'uri' => "https://...." . $ops),
                    ),
                    ),
            2 => array(
                '@type' => "OpenUri",
                'name' => "View Quotation",
                'targets' => array(
                0 => array(
                    'os' => "default",
                    'uri' => "https://....". $newUrl),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

We have added the feature to not show "See More" buttons if there are actions in the message. This will be available soon to all our users.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an update on this feature?  I would love to be able to completely eliminate "See More", "Expand All", "<N> replies from ..." and anything else that prevents ALL content, everywhere in Microsoft Teams, from automatically being expanded / displayed.

Comment: Still not such setting... Teams sucks